# Contextual meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading an article and read the following line.
This article is about political situation in Tamil Nadu in India.

.It helped that the party was in power when she died; otherwise, the district-level leaders might have begun pulling in different directions whether or not Ms. Sasikala became the general secretary. Mr. Stalin can afford to bide his time to see how the AIADMK holds in the post-Jayalalithaa phase and if the **visible signs of cadre disenchantment with Ms. Sasikala become accentuated.**

Now I did not understand the line marked in bold.
The article is from The Hindu. Here's a link to it

http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/Stalin-at-the-helm/article16988824.ece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  That's a mouthful.  Nice writing though.

A *cadre* is a closely-knit or aligned *group* of people, united for a purpose.

> With high-profile leaders, and a *cadre* of business executives in support of legislative action, she is hopeful lawmakers will get a bill passed.

To be *disenchanted* is to lose the feeling that something is special or extraordinary in some way.

> However, all of these points exacerbate a growing *disenchantment* with Washington’s inability to provide the American Dream to working-class America.

To *accentuate* means to intensify, or enhance in some way.

> The sautéed crimini mushrooms and truffle mayo *accentuated* the already flavorful patty in the hamburger.

Put it together and the author suggests that Mr. Stalin can wait and see if a particular group of lawmakers will grow less likely to follow Ms. Sasikala as time passes, as they like her less.